# angularjs two states one controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I'm sorry I don't even know how to name the title.
I am implementing a blog page as I am learning angularjs.

I have my app.config

```
    .state('blogs', {
        url: '/blogs',
        templateUrl: 'template/partial-blogs.html',
        controller:'blogsController'
    })
    .state('blogdetail', {
        url: '/blogs/:blogTitle',
        templateUrl: 'template/partial-blog-detail.html',
        controller:'blogsController'
    })
```

then I have a controller "blogsController":

```
.controller('blogsController',function($scope,$http,$location){ 
var refresh = function(){
        $http.get('/retrieveblogs').success(function(response){
        $scope.articles = response;
        $scope.blog=null;
    });
};
refresh();
$scope.readmore = function(item){    
    $scope.selectedBlog = item;
    $location.path('/blogs/'+$scope.selectedBlog.title);
};
```

})

then I have two html files, one is for displaying all the blogs and the other is a detail page for a selected blog

1. the page for all the blogs:

   ```
       <div ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:searchText | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize|limitTo:pageSize" class="wholearticle">
           <h1>{{article.title}}</h3>
           <div class="well poster">
               <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i>{{article.author}}</span>
               <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>{{article.posttime|date:'medium'}}</span>
           </div>
           <p class="well blogbody">{{article.body|limitTo:500}}</p>
               <a ng-click="readmore(article)">Read More</a>
           <div class="col-xs-12"><hr/></div>
       </div>
   ```
2. the page for a specific blog:

   ```
           <h1>{{selectedBlog.title}}</h3>
           <div class="well">
               <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i>{{selectedBlog.author}}</span>
               <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>{{selectedBlog.posttime|date:'medium'}}</span>
           </div>
           <p class="well blogbody">{{selectedBlog.body}}</p>
   ```

I have problems:

1. when I click the link "read more", the blog detail page doesn't show the blog.  However, the url is good with the specific blog's title appended to the url. It seems like the $scope.selectedBlog is empty.
2. Can I use "ui-sref" on the link but also able to append the blog title to the url dynamicly?

e.g.

```
<a ng-click="readmore(article)" ui-sref="???">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to `$location.path('/blogs/'+$scope.selectedBlog.title);` the controller is re-initialized so `$scope.selectedBlog = item;` that had a value before you redirected, now is null.

You should use 2 controllers: one for the list of articles, another for a single article, there's no reason to use just one.

Your routes would look like :

```
.state('blogs', {
        url: '/blogs',
        templateUrl: 'template/partial-blogs.html',
        controller:'blogsController'
    })
    .state('blogs.article', {
        //now this state is a child of blogs (that's what the . does in the name)
        url: '/:articleId/:blogTitle',
        templateUrl: 'template/partial-blog-detail.html',
        controller:'blogArticleController'
    })
```

Controllers:

```
.controller('blogsController',function($scope,$http,$state){ 
   var refresh = function(){
        $http.get('/retrieveblogs').success(function(response){
        $scope.articles = response;
        $scope.blog=null;
    });
   };
   refresh();
   $scope.readmore = function(item){    
     $state.go('blogs.article', {articleId: item.id, blogTitle: item.title});
   }
 })
.controller('blogArticleController',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){ 
   var refresh = function(){
        $http.get('/retrieveblog_article_by_id from $routeParams').success(function(response){
        $scope.article = response;
    });
};
};
```

`item.title` should be a string with just letters and numbers. I think `$state.go` will url encode .. but I haven't checked.

Hope this sets you on the right track.

Comment: thx.  I wanted to pass the selected blog to the detail page so that I don't need to send request to server. So I guess have to create a service to pass variable between controllers

Comment: You could have a separate service that loads the data and you just check to see if the article is already loaded or not.